# How to take certain parts of a string in React Native?

Tags: javascript, string, react-native

I have this string :

```
Wed May 09 2018 13:10:47 GMT+0700 (WIB)
```

I want to only pick :

```
May 09 2018
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: `.slice(4, 15)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I got this error : date.slice is not a function

What you have is a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object rather than a string.

You can do

```
date.toString().slice(4, 15)
```

Alternatively, if you want a more readable and flexible solution (eg. display a different date format, support different languages etc), you can use the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const date = new Date();
moment(date).format('MMM DD YYYY');
```

This comes at the cost of larger bundle size if `momentjs` was not already a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already gave an answer in the comment

I give a complete example:

```
const str = 'Wed May 09 2018 13:10:47 GMT+0700 (WIB)';
console.log(str.slice(4, 15)); // May 09 2018
```

Comment: `date.toString().slice(4, 15)`
or
`new Date().toString().slice(4, 15)`